# More efficient way to async load javascript files

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to load file files asynchronously with javascript, here is the code:

```
        var jsFiles = [ 'js/enscroll.min.js', 
                        'js/jp_custom.js', 
                        'js/jquery.uploadifive.js', 
                        'js/raphael-min.js', 
                        'js/pgloader.js', 
                        'js/jquery.custom.js' ];

        for( var i=0, j=jsFiles.length; i < j; i++ ){
            var file = jsFiles.shift();
            asyncLoader(file, i);
        }

        function asyncLoader( filename, position, fileType ){
            var type = typeof fileType == "undefined" ? "script" : fileType, 
                resource = document.createElement(type), 
                script = document.getElementsByTagName(type)[position+1];

            resource.src  = filename;
            resource.type = "text/javascript";

            script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
        }
```

i am useing this code under the `<head></head>` tag means in the top of the file, and here is how do used the files related functionalities:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        // Start to use the related files
    });
})
```

at the bottom of the page so that after load the window my files working properly, i just want to know is this the best way to reduce the page load time(only javascript)? or what i have to with it to make it more efficient?

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery?

Comment: @Bergi :) just before this script part, not through async, because all these included files are related to jQuery that why i inserted jquery before calling this async part.

Comment: @Bergi as you notice the `script = document.getElementsByTagName(type)[position+1];` i am using `position+1` because on the first place(`0`) i already inserted the jQuery file.

Comment: @jogesh_pi reducing requests means better _loading performance_ (not true all the time but for most cases) so if you have scripts that you load on all (or most of the pages) think over combining them into one file. (similar to image sprites)

Comment: @t.niese hmm, this is also a good point.

Comment: Why not use an existing library like Lab.js (http://labjs.com/) which also allows you to handle dependencies between files?

Comment: @RobWillis libs like _require_ and _labjs_ could increase performance, but could also have negative effects that depends on the use case (e.g. if scripts are loaded cross domain). This needs to be checked individually for each use case.